# SonarQube doesn't display unit test coverage

Tags: unit-testing, sonarqube, code-coverage, cobertura, sonarqube-web

I'm trying to get SonarQube to display unit test coverage generated by cobertura, however when I add unit test coverage widget to the home dashbord I get following error:

[image]

I did add coberture plugin to SonarQube and configured reports file location specific to the project I'm using in sonar. Also added configuration to sonar.properties :

```
sonar.projectBaseDir=<..>\src
sonar.dynamicAnalysis=reuseReports
sonar.cobertura.reportPath=<..>\target\site\cobertura\coverage.xml
sonar.java.coveragePlugin=cobertura
```

Absolute paths here.

- SonarQube version I'm using is 5.6
- Cobertura - 2.1.1

I don't have jenkins set up and don't use maven build, the coverage report was generated with ant task.

Did read all the documentations and simply can't understand what I need to get reports visualized in sonar, which is simply all I need.

Comment: Unit Test Coverage is a project-specific widget. Did you configure it to specify a project?

Comment: Yeah I did (if you dont specify it, the widget just displays message asking to configure it)